# Apache SSL Proxypass gives unsecured content for zope

Tags: apache, plone, zope

Had hit a roadblock with the apache configuration trying to redirect or proxy to other webservers. Have google for quite a while but am stuck as mentioned in the scenario below. Apart from using apache for some out of the box web applications like Plone, cmdbuild, etc., I don’t have much experience with apache. Leaving security aside for the configuration for Apache, am I trying to achieve something the wrong way. Do give me your views and other possible ways to achieve what I am trying to do. Am planning to run all the sites under https.

Scenario:

Server 1 – 10.0.0.1 (CentOS 6.5)
Apache (version 2.2.5) running on port 80 (SSL enabled) – Main Web Server
Zope (Plone) running on port 8080
    Sites:

```
http://10.0.0.1:8080/site1

http://10.0.0.1:8080/site2
```

Server 2 – 10.0.0.2 (CentOS 6.5)
    Tomcat running on port 8080
    Sites: `http://10.0.0.3:8080/site3` 
Server 3 – 10.0.0.3 (Windows Server 2008)
    IIS running on port 80
    Sites: `http://10.0.0.4/site4`

If ProxyPass and Proxy PassReverse is used on the apache ssl.conf like below:

```
ProxyPass /site1 http://10.0.0.1:8080/site1
ProxyPassReverse /site1 http://10.0.0.1:8080/site1

ProxyPass /site2 http://10.0.0.1:8080/site2 
ProxyPassReverse /site2 http://10.0.0.1:8080/site2 

ProxyPass /site3 http://10.0.0.2:8080/site3 
ProxyPassReverse /site3 http://10.0.0.2:8080/site3 

ProxyPass /site4 http://10.0.0.1:8080/site4 
ProxyPassReverse /site4 http://10.0.0.1:8080/site4
```

Site 3 and Site 4 are working properly fine with the ssl enabled but site 1 and site 2 (running under localhost zope) are working too but the contents are not showing properly because

“Connection Partially Encrypted
Parts of the page you are viewing were not encrypted …..”

If RewriteEngine is used instead of ProxyPass as shown below, both site1 and site2 runs perfectly under ssl.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://10.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/%{SERVER_NAME}:443/site1/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
```

But the other sites site3 and site4 are not reachable.

Apache httpd.conf just had a permanent redirect to https

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Redirect permanent / https://10.0.0.1/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your rewrite rule is working for anything other than site1, it's because acquisition is making other sites appear inside site1. You don't want to depend on that.

Instead, have a separate rewrite rule for each site:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/site1(.*) http://10.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/{SERVER_NAME}:443/site1/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
    RewriteRule ^/site2(.*) http://10.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/{SERVER_NAME}:443/site2/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]   
    RewriteRule ^/site3(.*) http://10.0.0.2:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/{SERVER_NAME}:443/site3/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]    
    RewriteRule ^/site4(.*) http://10.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/{SERVER_NAME}:443/site4/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
```

Don't try to do this with one rewrite rule, or you'll expose your Zope root via proxy. A bad idea.

Comment: Hi Steve, I have tried the way you suggested by writing 4 rewrite rule but for site3 running on tomcat on a different server is giving a http Status 404 error saying that "/VirtualHostBase/https/10.0.0.1:443/site3/VirtualHostRoot/" the requested resource is not available. It's the same for site 4 which is running on IIS on a different IP too.

Comment: When I looked at your original ruleset, I didn't notice that you had site3 running on a different IP. I just edited the rule set in the reply to match your original. For site 4, you had the same IP as 1 and 2.

Also, if site 4 is running on IIS (not Zope), you won't want the "VirtualHost..." markers, which are Zope specific. You may need to use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse for those, as I don't believe IIS has any equivalent to Zope's internal rewriter (Virtual Host Monster).

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks a lot for the showing me the correct direction to do what I wanted to achieve. As uggested, I used proxypass for the IIS site and rewite rules for my plone sites. Initially, the rewrite rules had some issue in showing the sites correctly as unsecured contents are not shown. I tried the rewrite rule witch and used the generated codes for my two sites, which is a bit different from the rewrite rule that we had used.Now, the sites are working perfectly showing all the contents as secured. Thanks once again.